# How to extract subimages of an image programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cgimageref

I tried to take a part of an `UIImage` using Objective-C, but can't find anything about how to do this. I'd like help figuring out how to do this and the steps involved.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just make out of one image two separeted images.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you a we as opposed to an I? Do you also refer to yourself as The Many?

Comment: No, we are two people searching for an answer.

Comment: In that case, it might be better to stick with "I" regardless, seeing as you probably don't want to explain that every time you use "we" and it looks weird. Shame you ignored the System Shock reference, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. This splits the image in two parts, more speciffically in half.

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theImageYouWantToSplit.png"];
CGImageRef temporaryImageReference = image.CGImage;
CGImageRef topImageReference = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(temporaryImageReference, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height / 2.0));
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImageReference];
CGImageRelease(topImageReference);

CGImageRef bottomImageReference = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(temporaryImageReference, CGRectMake(0, image.size.height / 2.0,  image.size.width, image.size.height / 2.0));
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImageReference];
CGImageRelease(bottomImageReference);
```